# Ist ein Verb im Infinitiv vorfeldfähig?

Tags: sentence-structure, infinitive

Ist ein Verb in Infinitiv vorfeldfähig?

> z.B. *Abfahren könnten wir um 9 Uhr.*

Ich habe diesen Satz geschrieben, ohne zu überlegen. Ich weiß nicht woher dieser Satzbau kam. Zwar hatte ich eine Verbliste, etwa

> {frühstücken,abfahren,essen,…}

und wollte eins betonen. Den Effekt hätte vielleicht

> Um 9 Uhr könnten wir abfahren.

nicht, oder? Oder ist das schlecher Stil?

---

Auf [canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Wortstellung/Stellungsfeld/Vorfeld.html) habe ich was gefunden, aber da wird nur *Infinitiv+zu* in Betracht gezogen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ja, der Infinitiv ist wie im Prinzip jeder Teil des Prädikats vorfeldfähig. Es ist auch überhaupt nicht merkwürdig oder gestelzt und wird auch umgangssprachlich gemacht.

> Gesehen hab' den Film nicht aber ich hab davon gehört.
>   Zum Ausgehen ist das ganz nett aber wohnen will ich da nicht.
>   Kochen lernen kann jeder.

Nur bei Präfixen klingt es ein wenig komisch

> An mache ich die Heizung nur wenn ich sie brauche.
>   Aus schlafe ich morgen.
>   (sagt man nur zum Spaß und funktioniert nur mit starker Betonung auf "aus")

Comment: Nur um es nochmal zu betonen: Nur der vom Infinitiv abgetrennte Präfix ist's, der komisch klingt: "Ausschlafen kann ich ja am Wochenende"